# src of Bootstrap.min.js not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code here. When I tried it, the dropdown of the topbar nav isn't working. However, when I tried to remove the src for the bootstrap.min.js, it is now working.

Here is the code. I also have it in JSFiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/1951c886/).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../pages/admin/admin-index.php">
              <img src="" alt="">
           </a>
    </div>
         <!-- Top Menu Items -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
         <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin User <b class="fa fa-angle-down"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalChangePassword"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Password</a></li>
                 <li class="divider"></li>
                 <li><a href="../php/Logout.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<script src="../../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery-validation-1.15.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/sidebar-topbar.js"></script>

<script>
        $("#formChangePassword").validate({
            //validation code
        });
</script>
```

I am using this code as a php file. I include this in the other php files I have using this code.

```
<?php
     include '../include/Nav.php';
?>
```

This is somehow affecting the way these codes work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sounds like a conflict. Look at your console and check your path

Comment: There's nothing in the console. Forgot to include that.

Comment: try using same html not in php file, to determine the scope of the problem

Comment: When I use it in html, it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is arising because you are including the bootstrap `cdn` `twice` in your file. You are including the cdn in the `nav.php` and again in the other php file.

It is a very common problem and you should include the `cdn only once` per page.

So, **the solution is remove the bootstrap cdns from nav.php** and then include it in other php files.